# AWS Aurora performance schema, how to enable events_statements_history

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm working with an aurora instance. I've updated my parameter group to turn on performance schema and restarted the instance. However `events_statements_history` is turned off.

Am I missing something or how can this be achieved?

```
select * from setup_consumers where name like 'events%statement%';
+--------------------------------+---------+
| NAME                           | ENABLED |
+--------------------------------+---------+
| events_statements_current      | YES     |
| events_statements_history      | NO      |
| events_statements_history_long | NO      |
+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 4):

It is currently not possible to set this anywhere in the AWS console. You can execute this to turn it on:

```
use performance_schema; update setup_consumers set enabled='yes' WHERE name = 'events_statements_history';"
```

However, this must be re-done every time the Aurora instance is restarted.

```
MySQL > show global variables like 'performance_schema';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| performance_schema | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

use performance_schema;

MySQL [performance_schema]> select * from setup_consumers WHERE name = 'events_statements_history';
+---------------------------+---------+
| NAME                      | ENABLED |
+---------------------------+---------+
| events_statements_history | NO      |
+---------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [performance_schema]> update setup_consumers set enabled='yes' 
WHERE name = 'events_statements_history';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MySQL [performance_schema]> select * from setup_consumers WHERE name = 
'events_statements_history';
+---------------------------+---------+
| NAME                      | ENABLED |
+---------------------------+---------+
| events_statements_history | YES     |
+---------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```